# Windows 7 Profiles and Domains

Tags: windows-7, domain, user-profile

I have a local user account I've been using, and I recently joined my laptop to my domain and created a user.

How can I copy my local user settings over to the domain user without having to manually redo all my settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to the computer with an administrative user account that is **not** the local profile you want to copy or the domain profile you want to apply the settings to. Once logged in, go into Control Panel\System, choose Advanced System Settings, and in the window that appears choose the Advanced tab and select User Profiles. Select the local user profile in the list and then click the Copy To button, then browse to the domain profile that you'd like to apply the settings to and press Ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the user state migration tool: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722344(WS.10).aspx